# Ember.js 2. Nested routes but non-nested templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember.js-2

First of all, thank you all for your efforts in this forum.

I have this situation:

- mysite.com/authors (list of authors)
- mysite.com/author/1 (author 1)
- mysite.com/book/1 (book 1 of author 1)
- mysite.com/cart/1 (cart page of book 1 of author 1)

I need an url like this:

**mysite.com/author/1/1/cart**

but I don't want nested template (every page is different and I don't want same info in many page).

**Is there a way to have that URL?**

My actual **router.js** is this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('login');
  this.route('authors', {path: '/authors'});
  this.route('author', {path: '/author/:author_id'});
  this.route('book', {path: '/book/:book_id'});
  this.route('cart', {path: '/cart/:cart_id'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

### Multiple dynamic segments

Just don't nest your routes but have multiple dynamic segments. Thats possible:

```
this.route('cart', {path: '/cart/:author_id/:cart_id'});
```

This will give you a route like this:

**`/cart/1/A`**
this will render the `cart` route with the author 1 and the cart A

### Nest but just don't put anything into the parent route

So you can have this router:

```
this.route('author', {path: '/author/:author_id'}, function() {
  this.route('cart', {path: '/cart/:cart_id'});
});
```

Now your problem is that if you put the author data into the `/author` route its also visible on the `author.cart` route. But a simple solution is to keep the `author` route empty, with just `{{outlet}}` as the template and put your author stuff into the `author.index` route.

This will give you routes like this:

**`/author/1`**
this will render the `author.index` route with the author 1

**`/author/1/cart/A`**
this will render the `author.cart` route with the author 1 and the cart A

Comment: Ok. It works. But I have to change also the directory of my `routes` files, right? From `routes/authors/book.js` to `routes/authors/books/book/index.js`?

Comment: Or I'm wrong completely? What the directories schema?

Comment: I have a problem with `routs/author/index.js`, in the `model(params)` function. The `params` is an empty object! **Why?**

Comment: Thats expected. you get the params in the `author` route, and can use `modelFor` to get the model of the `author` route. Thats different if you use multiple dynamic segments.